# SQL search query using LIKE and WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I need your help.

This is my Products Table:

```
 id       name       type
 1        item 1     A
 2        item 2     A
 3        item 3     B
 4        item 4     B
```

etc...

I want to search all possible records which start with item in **Type A**

I have this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM products 
 WHERE type = 'A'
 OR name LIKE '%item%';
```

But I'm getting possible records from other types. How can I filter to only display Type A? Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps `AND` instead of `OR`

Comment: LIKE '%item%' will find rows containing item, not just starting with item. Remove first % if you want starting item only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `AND` instead of `OR`

```
 SELECT * FROM products 
 WHERE type = 'A'
 AND name LIKE 'item%';
```

Comment: thanks it works! Accepting your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: You can remove first %, since the name is supposed to start with item.